# Is java 8 supported by LiveCycle ES4?

Tags: java, livecycle

Is java 8 supported by LiveCycle ES4 ?

I could not find the information in Adobe support, even in "LiveCycle Help / Adobe LiveCycle ES4 Supported Platforms" (http://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/help/livecycle-es4-supported-platforms.html)

Does anyone have experience with Java 8 + ES4 ?

Best regards,

Sam

Comment: If you are asking if it officially supported, then you have to assume that unless they say it is supported, it is not.  Are you asking if "supported" means, it kind of works, but not officially support?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a customer support issue, not a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of whether it works or not (because it likely will), if your platform is not listed in the Supported Platforms document if you run into difficulties you will be required to duplicate the issue on a supported platform.